# Varnish Not caching wordpress website. Tried some solutions present in blogs. Nothing worked for me

Tags: wordpress, varnish, varnish-vcl, varnish-4

I was able to configure varnish, but it is not caching i guess. In the response header, i see these attributes:

```
Url : corp.zip.pr

Age →0 
Via →1.1 varnish-v4 
X-Varnish →98319
```

My default.vcl file is as below:

```
# Marker to tell the VCL compiler that this VCL has been adapted to the 
# new 4.0 format. 
vcl 4.0; 

# Default backend definition. Set this to point to your content server. 
backend default { 
.host = "127.0.0.1"; 
.port = "8080"; 
} 

sub vcl_recv { 
# Happens before we check if we have this in cache already. 
# 
# Typically you clean up the request here, removing cookies you don't need, 
# rewriting the request, etc. 

if (req.method == "PURGE") { 

if (req.http.X-Purge-Method == "regex") { 

ban("req.url ~ " + req.url + " && req.http.host ~ " + req.http.host); 

return (synth(200, "Banned.")); 

} else { 

return (purge); 

} 
} 


if (req.url ~ "wp-admin|wp-login") { 
return (pass); 

} 

if (!(req.url ~ "wp-(login|admin)")) {
                unset req.http.cookie;
}


set req.http.cookie = regsuball(req.http.cookie, "wp-settings-d+=[^;]+(; )?", ""); 

set req.http.cookie = regsuball(req.http.cookie, "wp-settings-time-d+=[^;]+(; )?", ""); 

set req.http.cookie = regsuball(req.http.cookie, "wordpress_test_cookie=[^;]+(; )?", ""); 

if (req.http.cookie == "") { 

unset req.http.cookie; 
} 
} 

sub vcl_backend_response { 
# Happens after we have read the response headers from the backend. 
# 
# Here you clean the response headers, removing silly Set-Cookie headers 
# and other mistakes your backend does. 


if (beresp.ttl == 120s) { 

set beresp.ttl = 600s; 

} 
} 

sub vcl_deliver { 
# Happens when we have all the pieces we need, and are about to send the 
# response to the client. 
# 
# You can do accounting or modifying the final object here. 
}
```

Moreover, varnishlog is not working. when i type varnishlog in the terminal, i see the below message.

> Cannot open /opt/bitnami/varnish/var/varnish/_.vsm: No such file or directory

i checked the file location. `_.vsm` is not present here. i checked for the vsm location used by varnishd process. it was different

```
/var/lib/varnish/ip-172-31-10-1/
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have `return (hash);` In your `vcl_recv` function, add it at the end of function body, restart varnish and check if it work.

I thing your vcl is weird, maybe try this for example https://www.htpcguides.com/configure-wordpress-varnish-4-cache-with-apache-or-nginx/

Comment: Excellent answer, please also update your file and include HTTPS as well.